# Anchor tag disable

Tags: jquery

I have to enable and disable the anchors based on index ,eg : when index is 3 or more &gt anchor should be disabled . 
I have written the following code snipet but the anchor is not getting disabled when index is 3 .

```
if(index == 3){
     $("#anchor2").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault(); 
                return false;
        });
 }
```

Comment: post all of your relevant html and javascript. the above doesnt really help in understanding locating the issue

Comment: by 'index', you mean the anchor's index? or is this a variable?

Comment: @Banana index is a variable .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#anchor2').click(function (e) {
    if (index >= 3) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    //if index<3 follow the link normally
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just modify the scenario as:

```js
    index=3;//change the value andcheck the result
    $('#anchor2').click(function (e) {
        if (index == 3) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        } else {
            alert('I am Enabled Now');
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="anchor2" href="#">Click me!</a>
```

Comment: You don't need to prevent default if you are returning false

Comment: yes I know that but this is the best practice per say :)

Comment: *return false from within a jQuery event handler is effectively the same as calling both e.preventDefault and e.stopPropagation on the passed jQuery.Event object.*

Answer (score 1):

try this trick:

```
<a href="#" data-disabled >Click Here! disabled</a>

$('a[data-disabled]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('disabled');
});
```

just put a `data-disabled` attribute on your 3rd anchor tag.

**[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/48nzr2pf/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can do this css trick:

```
if(index == 3){
    $("#anchor2").css('pointer-events', 'none');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);'>some text</a>
```